# Видео вместо фона сайта

Tags: css3, видео, html5

Здравствуйте.

Вот решил установить видео вместо фона.
Все вроде нормально, но проблема в том, что при сжатии размера окна браузера видео обрезается слева направо.

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы обрезка шла по обеим краям, т.е. был виден центр видео?
Вот пример для демонстрации: [Установка видео для фона сайта с помощью HTML5 | rudebox.org.ua](http://www.rudebox.org.ua/demo/installation-video-to-background-with-site-using-html5/)

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Может быть, вам подойдет [такой вариант (ссылка)](http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/o0cL9hdx/):

html:

```
<div id="videoContainer">
    <video autoplay="" loop="" poster="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23834858/videos/bck.jpg">
        <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23834858/videos/WD0221.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23834858/videos/WD0221.webmsd.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.videoContainer {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Кажется, неплохо масштабируется, впрочем, навено, есть варианты и получше. Мне тоже было бы интересно о них узнать. Сайты с видео обычно выглядят прикольнее. :)

P.S. Вот тут есть [интересный пример](http://zerosixthree.se/create-a-responsive-header-video-with-graceful-degradation/) с использованием JavaScript и [демонстрация его работы](http://zerosixthree.se/labs/video-header/).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но это не то что хотел. Планируется, чтобы видео было в качестве фона и был растянут на всю ширину экрана.
Вот как вот тут  - https://5minutemarketing.leadpages.net/experience/. 
Если поиграться с разрешением экрана, то видео красиво подстраивается.

Answer (score 0):

[Посмотреть пример](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPXKqb)

Comment: Вы знаете, я этот пример тоже видел, мне кажется, там видео тоже обрезается при определённых условиях... http://radikal.ru/fp/2dd93644234643418f0c1ffe4c32bd83

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ, но предоставленный пример - это не то.
Разобрался, скачал js код, примененный на этом сайте, и подключил у себя. И в конце js  имеется строчка, где подключается само видео.
Подключаешь  - tracking.js (тоже можно взять с этого же сайта).
Для див добавляешь строчку

```
onload="leadPagesOnLoadFn();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вычислять ширину браузера и добавлять к видео отрицательный `margin-left`, который равен половине разности между размером окна браузера и размером видео. А при ресайзе пересчитывать формулу.  [Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/2sgmps3q/2/) с шириной видео 864px.

Если ширина браузера больше этой ширины, то видео показывается в обычном варианте.

**UPD.** Посмотрел тот пример, что вы дали к первому ответу, они вместо `margin-left` используют просто `left`, можете попробовать, формула в принципе та же.